# Understanding output of EXPLAIN MYSQL command

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running this command on a `QOVENDOR` table.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM QOVENDOR
WHERE V_NAME LIKE "B%"
ORDER BY V_AREACODE
```

QOVENDOR table:

```
CREATE TABLE `qovendor` (
  `V_CODE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `V_NAME` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `V_CONTACT` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `V_AREACODE` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `V_PHONE` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `V_STATE` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `V_ORDER` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`V_CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The output I get is:

```
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | QOVENDOR | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   15 | Using where; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

This information should help me build more efficient queries, but I am having a hard time understanding how. The only non null column with some intersteing information is Extra, select_ype, Type and Rows. I am indeed using where clause, not sure what `Using filesort` means, besides that it relates to order by. How can I deduce if this query is the most efficient as it can be?

For evaluating performance I should have some sort of CPU Cost, and time data (like Oracle DBMS provides with EXPLAIN command).

Comment: you have a small table (15 rows) and a basic query. theres nothing really you can do to make this more efficient. if your table had a million rows you would need to consider indexing V_NAME and V_AREACODE so that when you run your query mysql doesnt have to scan over the whole million rows to return a result

Comment: If you create an index on V_NAME it would be possible to use that index, but I'm not sure whether mysql is smart enough for that.

Comment: It is because there is nothing to show in your setup. Try using column V_CODE in your query WHERE clause and you will get some more information. Or create index on V_NAME column. In your current query there are no indexes to be used and thus nothing to explain.

Comment: refer this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL `explain` will not provide you with time, nor with CPU cost information. [MySQL documentation on explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) describes exactly the meaning of each column in the output:

| Column | JSON Name | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | select_id | The SELECT identifier |
| select_type | None | The SELECT type |
| table | table_name | The table for the output row |
| partitions | partitions | The matching partitions |
| type | access_type | The join type |
| possible_keys | possible_keys | The possible indexes to choose |
| key | key | The index actually chosen |
| key_len | key_length | The length of the chosen key |
| ref | ref | The columns compared to the index |
| rows | rows | Estimate of rows to be examined |
| filtered | filtered | Percentage of rows filtered by table condition |
| Extra | None | Additional information |

From a query optimisation point of view, probably the type, possible_keys, key, rows, and extra fields are the most important. Their detailed description can be found on the linked MySQL documentation.